# Drupal 7 Entity Reference in User Profile

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Client content type with an Image field named Logo.

Client
 - Image: Logo

I also have a User profile with an Entity Reference field name Featured Clients.

User 
 - Entity Reference

How do I create a View that will show the Client Image Logo of the Client Node referenced in the User profile?

Scenario:

User (example)
 - Entity reference for this 'example' user references Client node #1.

I want the image logo of that Client node #1 to show up in the User 'example' profile.

Hope that makes sense. I've been researching Contextual Filters and Entity References in Drupal 7, but I haven't found the right solution yet.

Comment: Add a new Relationship under advanced, and choose the entity reference field for it. Then you'll have access to the referred node's fields

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

When creating a View, under Relationships I selected the following:

- Profile referencing Content from field_some_featured_clients
- Require this Relationship is Checked

Under Contextual Filters, I selected the following:

- User ID
- Specify Validation Criteria >> User >> Allow both User IDs and string usernames
- When filter NOT available >> Provide Default Value >> User ID from URL

Under Fields, I selected the following:

- Content: Logo